# Difference between Magento 2 and Google Analytics Revenue with Cart Price Rules

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, google-analytics, price-rules

I want to know if you have any idea why when I set some Cart Price Rules, for example a 30% discount, is not reflected on my Google Analytics revenue.

Here is an example:

X product, full price: $100
With a Cart Price Rule Discount of 30%= $70 Total Order
Google Analytics Revenue: $100 (Discount doesn't apply)

Please let me know if you can help me.

Thanks in advance,
Lucas

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

Comment: And what method have you used to integrate Google analytics?

Comment: Google Tag Manager from Mageplaza Extensions

Comment: Then you need to speak to Mageplaza support. It’s either a misconfiguration or a bug in their module, in either case they should be able to help.